# mysql order by with a NOT unique rank?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Handle Ties When Ranking Results in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474390/how-do-i-handle-ties-when-ranking-results-in-mysql)

I'd like to order the table `Status` by `Activepoints` and insert the rank into a column `rank`.
It comes:

```
RANK   USERNAME   ACTIVEPOINTS

 1     monkey100     92
 2     fresnoJump    54
 3     otherUser9    54
```

but it should display NOT unique ranks like

```
RANK   USERNAME   ACTIVEPOINTS

 1     monkey100     92
 2     fresnoJump    54
 2     otherUser9    54
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are currently using?

Comment: If you added another user with 49 points, should their rank be `3` or `4`?

Comment: @simon of course `4` or not??

Answer (score 1):

I think this is solved with 2 UDF variables http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html.

```
SET @rank = 0, @previous_active_points = 0;
SELECT IF(@previous_active_points<>Activepoints,@rank:=@rank+1,@rank) AS rank,
@previous_active_points:=Activepoints,username,Activepoints 
FROM `status` ORDER BY Activepoints
```

Hope it helps!