# EXCEPT statement error

Tags: mysql, sql

I do not understand why this query is not working:

```
SELECT product.maker, product.model, product.type FROM product EXCEPT
(Select top 3 with ties product.maker, product.model, product.type  
FROM Product ORDER BY model DESC)
```

The database scheme consists of four tables:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

UPDATE: I actually tried inputting this code using mssql in the online site im in, but it still does not work. Could it be that its a possible site error (ie. something wrong with their DBMS). * NOT EXIST also does not seem to work, however I have used it before in other query questions on the site.

Comment: What error message are you getting when you run it?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXCEPT'.

Comment: im acutally not quite sure..i think both works..if not sql

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Handle Ties When Ranking Results in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474390/how-do-i-handle-ties-when-ranking-results-in-mysql)

Comment: dumbest comment ever just because my code has ties doesnt mean its the same question -_-

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can try this query as well

```
SELECT product.maker, product.model, product.type FROM product 
    MINUS
Select top 3 with ties product.maker, product.model, product.type  
FROM Product ORDER BY model DESC.
```

Hope by this you can achieve desired result.

Comment: Hi, i tired running your code but i got: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'

Comment: The code may be wrong coz i dont have your schema. but the Concept is right that mysql dosent support EXCEPT kayword so you have to use another method than that.

Comment: ya, i actually included the schema but someone deleted it. NOw i added it again, i dont think anything is wrong with the schema part

Comment: still doesnt work... i find it strange that the previous NOT EXIST query didnt work

Answer (score 0):

EXCEPT and TOP are [mssql](/questions/tagged/mssql) ([t-sql](/questions/tagged/t-sql)) keywords. Do you use MSSQL or MySQL as mentioned in tags to your question. If you try to run this query on MySQL the it is the reason of error because MySQL doesn't support these keywords.

In MySQL try this equivalent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
         product.maker, 
         product.model, 
         product.type FROM product 
         LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT product.maker, product.model, product.type  
              FROM Product 
              ORDER BY model DESC
              LIMIT 3
             ) as p2
             ON product.maker=p2.maker
                AND product.model = p2.model
                AND product.type = p2.type
          WHERE p2.maker IS NULL
                AND p2.model IS NULL
                AND p2.type IS NULL
```

Note: I've added `DISTINCT` to the main query to emulate [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx):

> EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not
>   also found on the right query

And also added `DISTINCT` into the subquery to emulate [TOP WITH TIES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Comment: thanks, I actually do not know if im using mysql or sql. Im actually doing online queries to problems...i think the site runs both mysql and sql. I am actually wondering why EXCEPT and NOT EXIST do not work. UPDATE: IN the site, it also lets me pick which dbms to use, it also doesnt work with mssql for some reason :(